# How to move word from registers to FPU in MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, double, mips

i want to know how to move two words from registers to FPU? I need to use them as one double precision.

Answer (score 0):

In MIPS32r2, use a sequence of:

```
MTC1  $s0, $f0
MTHC1 $s1, $f0
```

This assumes you have 32 bit CPU with a 64 bit FPU. `MTHC1` is a MIPS32 release 2 addition, so tools like SPIM and MARS likely won't implement it.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points to do that :( Can I send You some code? I have some problems with a little project..